# How can I get 2 triggers to work in a row?

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-dhf

After a DHF  entity document is created by a Harmonize flow, I want to trigger a new Harmonize flow to update triples of a related entity. I use a trigger for starting both Harmonize flows but I cannot get both to work at the same time.

If only the first trigger is enabled, the first Harmonize flow runs fine. If only the second trigger is enabled, this flow runs fine. If both triggers are enabled, no harmonized documents are created.

The first harmonize flow is triggered when a document is added to a collection called ‘input’. The harmonize flow creates an entity document in the collection ‘entity’. The second trigger will start on documents added to the ‘entity’ collection.

Both triggers are post-commit since I need data from the document that is to be saved.

Answer (score 0):

What do your error logs state? There should be a record of the triggers running and their output.

Generally, I'd recommend not relying on triggers tiered in this fashion to run sequential harmonize flows.

It sounds like you are wanting to do a single-step ingest (example here: https://github.com/marklogic/marklogic-data-hub/tree/4.x-develop/examples/single-step-ingest) and then once the entity is committed in the final database, to fire off the new harmonize flow to add the triples. This sounds like it'd get to where you need to go.

Comment: There is nothing in the logs ( no errors but also other log statements I added for testing purposes). It looks like the whole transaction is rolled back, including the one from the first harmonize flow. I will look into the single-step ingest code further to see if we can use this with DHF 3. At least this will save us from using one of the 2 triggers.

Comment: https://github.com/marklogic/marklogic-data-hub/tree/3.x-develop/examples/single-step-ingest is the 3.x example version.